# CP of 716, HP is 306. Battle with it vs one with higher CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a Chansey that has CP of 716, and it’s HP is 306- the highest HP of all of mine. Should I use in battles? Or use the Pokémon with higher CP? Like Vaporeon with CP 2188 HP 193. I have more Pokemon that have higher CP but none with that high of HP.

Comment: What type of battles is this for? For example, raid battles, against the gym, against other players. It also may depend which Pokemon you are against specifically.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: Chansey bad for attack. HP is not a good value to rank attackers on.

Each Pokemon has different stats in their attack, defense and health (HP). I am not talking about IV here (that's a whole different story, read for example [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/281686/80141) ), but about the base stats for each Pokemon. A Chansey has a very high base stat for HP (currently only outranked by its evolution, Blissey), but a very low attack. Hence it will last long in battle, but do not a lot of damage. Therefor it might not be an ideal choice to use it for battling, but it's better for defending gyms for example!

Very highover, a higher CP means better stats, meaning more damage. There are exceptions, like Chansey, Blissey, Slaking and maybe Aggron. And I probably forget a few less favorable, high CP Pokemon. Also, type-effectiveness is a very big thing! If you are taking down a Rayquaza, a Dragon-Flying Pokemon, ice is double super-effective against it and does 256% damage! Ghost is doing only 100% damage, so a Mamoswine or Glaceon (Ice Eevee) with the right moves might do a lot more damage than a higher CP Gengar!

These base stats are not visible in-game, but can be found on the internet. I do like Gamepress myself, because they have a (sometimes out of date) description with what moves to use for each Pokemon. Here is a link to the Chansey from the question: [here](https://gamepress.gg/pokemongo/pokemon/113).

edit: I just saw what Gamepress had to write about PVE with Chansey. This also says enough :)

[image: Gampress explanation about PVE with Chansey]

Comment: This is an incomplete answer as it really just covers some basics and PVE.  In PVP you want as low  attack and high HP as possible (outside of Master league, when you want ideally 100% stats)

Comment: @MattR I know, but that's also a different question. I linked to an answer that goes more into detailed about that